# Using a Materialized View with the Master table empty

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I was executing some tests with the concept of Materialized Views in Oracle and I wasn't able to answer this question, would a Materialized View fetch rows when the master table it was originally created from becomes empty? I have listed a sequence of events below to visualize what I have in mind,

1. Create a valid Materialized View based on a huge Master table

Here's an example

The Master table

```
CREATE TABLE master_tab
(                    
col1 varchar2(10),         
col2 varchar2(10), 
col3 varchar2(10),
tr_val1 number,
tr_val2 number,
tr_val3 number
)
```

The Materialized View definition

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mview_test
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND 
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS SELECT col1, col2
SUM(tr_val1), SUM(tr_val2)
FROM master_tab
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

2. At a later point in time, for some reason, the master table master_tab gets truncated
3. So, now, only the Materialized View has any data relevant to any query on the Master table master_tab

I wasn't very conversant with what Oracle does behind the scenes to fetch the correct data. Now, what happens when a query gets executed from an application looking for data from the Master table? For example, what happens when an application queries,

```
SELECT col1, col2
SUM(tr_val1), SUM(tr_val2)
FROM master_tab
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

1. What kind of decisions does Oracle take internally to fetch data from Materialized Views?
2. Would Oracle still retrieve the correct data from the Materialized View even if the Master table is empty?
3. If the answer to #2 is yes, does it mean that as long as the Materialized View isn't refreshed again, Oracle will still be able to fetch data for all queries looking for data from the Master?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What sort of tests were executing that you couldn't run a test for this case?

Comment: @APC -  I have posted my question here after executing quite a number of tests. First, I wasn't sure if there was a way to validate if my application is indeed using the Materialized View for all relevant queries on the Master table. Second, to test the scenario in question, I truncated the Master only to see all my queries return no values at all. I couldn't make out if this is due to the application still using the Master table for all its data (in-spite of there being a Materialized View for a specific combination of columns) or due to a probable standard Materialized View behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try to answer your questions:

1. To use query rewrite and have the data fetched from MV, the following is checked: a) Query re-write enabled (Session) b) Query re-write enabled (MV) and c) Re-write integrity check (I think this is where you need to control)

The above in addition to the check on the SQL itself if it can be rewritten using a MV (you can use `DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_REWRITE` on the SQL to advise if rewrite is possible and which MV are used

2. The integrity level `QUERY_RESRITE_INTEGRITY`is used to see if it is allowed to use query rewrite or not. The default is `ENFORCED`, and can be `TRUSTED` or `STALE_TOLERATED`. In your case, if it is `TRUSTED` or `STALE_TOLERATED`, the query would still be rewritten and the data will be retrieved from MV
3. I believe Yes, given 2

Comment: Thanks for your response. I now understand that the issue was with the QUERY_REWRITE_INTEGRITY setting. I had originally not changed it and it had the default value ENFORCED at the system level. After changing the value to STALE_TOLERATED, I could make the query on the master table fetch values from the Materialized View even when the master was empty